# How to play an effect in reverse

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

In one function I am calling the play method on an effect and in another I am calling the reverse method. The play method works but the reverse method does not. It appears that the propertyChangesArray is used to store the previous effect start values but that property is null when calling reverse. How do I do this?

Code:

```
        private var targetEffect:SetAction = new SetAction();
        public var sequence:Sequence = new Sequence();

        protected function play_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            targetEffect.target = sparkImage;
            targetEffect.property = "width";
            targetEffect.captureStartValues();
            targetEffect.value = 300;
            trace("properties change array " + targetEffect.mx_internal::propertyChangesArray); // [Object]

            if (sequence.children.length==0) {
                sequence.addChild(targetEffect);
            }


            sequence.captureStartValues();
            trace("properties change array " + sequence.mx_internal::propertyChangesArray); // [Object]
            sequence.play();
        }


        protected function reverse_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            var o:Object = targetEffect.mx_internal::propertyChangesArray;
            trace("reverse properties change array " + o); // null
            o = sequence.mx_internal::propertyChangesArray;
            trace("reverse  " + o); // null
            targetEffect.reverse();
            sequence.reverse();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

After calling reverse(), you need to call play():

```
targetEffect.reverse(  );
targetEffect.play(  );
```

Comment: I tried it this morning before posting (though obviously not using your effect sequence)

Comment: thanks. i think that would work in Flex 3 but in Flex 4 it's play(null, true). So it appears that it is getting garbage collected by the deleteInstance method that is called at the end of the effect. It is not possible to play the effect in reverse after the master effect is complete.